# create an adjustable playlist with ruby

Tags: ruby, playlist

I'm not sure why my code will not pass the corresponding test.  Each time I try the code, the following error is reported:  "rb:60:in `<main>': undefined local variable or method`track' for main:Object (NameError)."  What can I do without editing the tests?  Thanks!  Open to another approach...thanks!
**strong text**

```
class Song
  attr_reader :song 
  def initialize(song, artist)
    @song = song
    @artist = artist
  end
  def play
   puts "#{@song}by #{@artist}"
  end
end

class Playlist
  def initialize(player_list)
    @player_list = player_list
  end

  def add(add_song)
      add_song.each do |song|
          @player_list << song
      end
  end

  def track_number
      @player_list.length 
  end

  def remove(remove_song)
      remove_song.each do |song|
          @player_list.delete(song)
      end
  end

  def includes?(from_list)
      i = 0
      from_list.each do |song|
          if @player_list.include?(song) 
                i+=1
          end
      end
      if i==from_list.length 
        true
      else 
         false
      end
   end

  def play_all
      @player_list.each do |song|
            song.play
      end
  end

  def display
      @player_list.each do |song|
          puts song.song 
      end
  end
end



 one_by_one = Song.new("One by One", "Sirenia")
 world_so_cold = Song.new("World So Cold", "Three Days Grace") 
 going_under = Song.new("Going Under", "Evanescence")

 my_playlist = Playlist.new(one_by_one, world_so_cold, going_under)

 lying_from_you = Song.new("Lying From You", "Linkin Park")
 angels = Song.new("Angels", "Within Temptation")

 my_playlist.add(lying_from_you, angels)
 p my_playlist.track_number == 5
 going_under.play
 my_playlist.remove(angels)
 p my_playlist.includes?(lying_from_you) == true
 my_playlist.play_all
 my_playlist.display
```

Comment: Hint: where is `track.new` defined? Anywhere? Bueller?

Comment: Spoiler Alert: `track.new` should be `Song.new` everywhere

Comment: Correct, as I transcribed the wrong version.  However, same problem remains...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call the "add" method for PlayList, it is expecting a single Song. However, the "add" method is trying to call .each() which would work for an array of Songs but not for a single song.

The best solution, without changing your test code, would be to remove the ".each" calls in the "add", "remove" and "includes?" methods for PlayList. Have them each add, remove or check for a single song at a time.